# How to start a new line from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have created this "shell" in jQuery:

Code: [link text](http://jsbin.com/aqiza/15/edit)

Demo: [link text](http://jsbin.com/aqiza/15/)

I need that every 100 chars, the prompt go in a new line below.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a high level, you're generating html from JavaScript, so any html which would work standalone will work when generated from JavaScript too. Some possibilities, with varying flexibility:

Pre-formatted text, insert newline `"\n"` characters:

```
<pre>
line one
line two
</pre>
```

Inserting break tags:

```
line one<br />
line two<br />
```

Or my favourite, use paragraph tags:

```
<p>line one</p>
<p>line two</p>
```

I like this because you can refer to each line in code as a single DOM element. Set this css to keep the lines side-by-side:

```
div.code-listing p { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Programaticaly, by concatenating `<br />` is the only way I can think of.

`word-wrap: break-word;`

Combined with a width should give you an approximation, but it won't be perfect.